# Prism, know when a WPF page is loaded

Tags: c#, .net, prism

I'm trying to change a couple things on an already existing .NET application that uses Prism 4.0 for its view management.  I don't know much about .NET, WPF, Prism, so sorry if this question is noob.  Basically my situation is this:

A button gets clicked to push a new page:

```
    private void CreateGraphCommandHandler()
    {
        // Request navigation
        RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, ScreenNames.GraphView);
        EventAggregator.GetEvent<CreateGraphMessage>().Publish(SelectedChart);
    }
```

In the CreateGraphCommandHandler method, it basically gets the appropriate data points and builds a chart of type FrameWorkElement.  It's using some third party library called Visifire to render the plot I believe.  Then there is a button to Save the image and go to the next page to check out some more charts.

Part of the Saving of the image looks like:

```
        void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
        {
            int aheight = (int)visual.ActualHeight;
            int awidth = (int)visual.ActualWidth;

            RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                awidth,
                aheight,
                96,
                96,
                PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            bitmap.Render(visual);
            BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
```

So from what I can tell, this call saves what's currently rendered on screen.

There's a new requirement to generate all the charts that the person can generate for the desired data set.  So basically, by pass all the screens and just chart the data, save it to the appropriate location.  The problem I am having is, when the next screen gets pushed to generate the first plot, I think Save gets called before the plot finishes rendering.

When the screen gets pushed to the page where the plot is created, this method gets called:

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<CreateGraphMessage>().Subscribe(CreateGraphHandler);
```

So I thought that at the end of the CreateGraphHandler method, I could just call the SaveChart() method (the same method that got called from a button press).  The problem is, when the SaveUsingEncoder method gets called, FrameworkElement visual is null.  So I'm assuming that the page is not loaded and Save errors out.  I was wondering if there was a way to wait for this page to finish loading the chart before I call SaveChart()?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use the `Loaded` event of the page to send another message to the `EventAggregator` letting the component responsible for plotting know that the page is loaded and can be rendered to a bitmap.